# Why is %c used in C?

Tags: c

According to K&R C section 1.6, a `char` is a type of integer. So why do we need `%c`. And why can't we use `%d` for everything?

Comment: @MaziarBouali Not necessarily.

Comment: `printf` needs to know the size of the argument in order to print it (to cast it appropriately, so to say). A `char` has size 1, an `int` has at least that, on most machines more. Also, when using `%c` you want a character printed, not a number.
In the `D` language, you would always use `%s` and let the compiler worry about the types.

Comment: @MatejNanut No, integer types smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` when being passed into a variadic function.

Comment: @Pubby: thank you, I didn't know that. However, there is still this ambiguity when using longs, which are integers and you can't (or shouldn't) use `%d` for them.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because `%d` will print the numeric character code of the `char`:

```
printf("%d", 'a');
```

prints `97` (on an ASCII system), while

```
printf("%c", 'a');
```

prints `a`.

Comment: And don't forget `scanf`: `%d` reads and converts numeric strings, where as `%c` reads and converts individual characters.

Answer (score 4):

While it's an integer, the `%c` interprets its numeric value as a character value for display. For instance for the character `a`:

If you used `%d` you'd get an integer, e.g., 97, the *internal* representation of the character `a`

vs

using `%c` to display the character '`a`' itself (if using ASCII)

I.e., it's a matter of *internal representation* vs *interpretation* for external purposes (such as with `printf`)

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, `%c` prints the ASCII representation of the character. `%d` prints its decimal value.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `%c`, you'll print (or scan) a character, or char. If you use `%d`, you'll print (or scan) an integer.

```
printf("%d", 0x70);
```

How will the machine would know that you want to output a character, not its equivalent ASCII value?

Answer (score -1):

%d think char is 32bit and print it like a integer, but %c convert int value of char to ascii character then print it.

Answer (score -1):

`%d` is used to print `decimal(integer)` number ,while `%c` is used to print `character`.If you try to print a character with `%d` format the computer will print the `ASCII` code of the character.